# Correct way of styling Android Lollipop 5.0 Toolbar

Tags: android, styling, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I have been banging my head over this for some time now without any luck. 
I am using the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in my App (which supports Android API 11 and above), and want to style it. Here is how I am trying it:

**My Activity Layout XML contains:**

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="?attr/foo" />
```

**res/values/attr.xml** contains (this is where I define my attributes):

```
        <attr name="foo" format="reference" />
```

**res/values/Themes.xml**:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme_one">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme_one" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
        <item name="foo">@style/foo_style</item>
        <!-- bunch of other styles -->
    </style>
```

**res/values/Styles.xml**:

```
<style name="foo_style" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarDark</item>
</style>
```

**res/values-v21/Themes.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme_one">
    <!-- some v21 specific items not related to toolbar like animations etc-->
</style>
```

**res/values-v21/Styles.xml**:

```
<style name="foo_style" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionBarDark</item> <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK !!! -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarDark</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">5dp</item>
</style>
```

This arrangement works fine for Android API v11 to v19.
My issues for v21 (I also tried 2 and 3 without the `android:` prefix with same result):

1) **android:background**  works fine!
2) **android:colorPrimaryDark** does not work!
3) **android:elevation** applies to the title of the `Toolbar` and the `Toolbar` buttons as below. Is this expected?
[image]

What am I missing? Clearly I am not doing the styling the correct way, but unable to find any resources which talk about `toolbar` styling!

Answer (score 1):

I got **colorPrimaryDark** to work by by moving the:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionBarDark</item>
```

from **res/values-v21/Styles.xml** to **res/values-v21/Themes.xml**.

I got the **elevation** to work by removing it from all styles or theme xmls, and putting it in the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` declaration.

Also, If I define another theme here and change it dynamically in the app using Content.setTheme(), the theme changes but the status bar color does not. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: try to remove the parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" from your foo_style

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I go it to work by adding it in the Toolbar declaration. Updated the answer.

Comment: you shouldn't use the android prefix for any of them with the new support library. Read: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/